# Lookup field Traversing giving an error for Invalid field

Tags: visualforce, lookup, externalid

I have a visual force page and it has a lookup field given below

```
<apex:inputField value="{!X.loan_Loan_Account__c}" required="true"
                                     label="CL Contract">
```

based on the above lookup field I have records populated given below

```
<apex:outputField value="{!X.loan_Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Status__c}"
                                      label="Payment Status"/>
```

In the controller I have a method called which populates the status field on populating the lookup field.

```
if (X.loan_Loan_Account__r == null) {
        X.loan_Loan_Account__r = new loan__Loan_Account__c();
    }
X.loan_Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Status__c = X.loan__Loan_Status__c;
```

This gives me an error saying

> Cannot specify both an external ID reference loan_Loan_Account__r and a salesforce id, loan_Loan_Account__c

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is your issue

The Object `X` has a foreign key field `loan_Loan_Account_c`. This field is set by the `apex:inputField`

Then you try and construct

`X.loan_Loan_Account__r` which is an Sobject.  You can't have both the foreign key (lookup) field populated at the same time as you have the Sobject populated when you are constructing sobjects outside of SOQL. It is somewhat different when you are querying as you can query both the foreign key and the fields in the lookup (parent) sobject and have both co-exist in the queried result object

So...

```
if (X.loan__Loan_Account__c != null) {
    X.loan__Loan_Account__c == null; // null out foreign key fld
    X.loan__Loan_Account__r = new loan__Loan_Account__c (
                                      id = ?? do you need this?
                                      loan__loan_status__c = X.loan__Loan_Status__c);
}
```

Now, I'm not sure what you are going to do with this data structure. If you do DML on the child, you will need to restore the parent's ID value to the foreign key (lookup) field before the DML.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must assign X.loan_Loan_Account__**c** instead of X.loan_Loan_Account__r. Also you must assign not "new loan__Loan_Account__c()" but the id of "new loan__Loan_Account__c()". And to gain id, you must insert "new loan__Loan_Account__c()".
So the code should look like:

```
if (X.loan_Loan_Account__c == null) {
    loan__Loan_Account__c newLoanAcc = new loan__Loan_Account__c();
    insert newLoanAcc;
    X.loan_Loan_Account__c = newLoanAcc.id;
}
X.loan_Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Status__c = X.loan__Loan_Status__c;
```